# Laravel Composer could not install tymon/jwt-auth

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php, laravel-9

Please assist, composer could not install tymon/jwt-auth:0.5.*

I had type :

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:0.5.*
```

i also tried to add the ff in projects composer.json:

```
    require {
....
"tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-master", 
....

}
```

and "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*" respectively

Plase note : I am new to laravel ...

**In the case of laravel 9.11:**

Typing this command:

```
    composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

OutPut an Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires tymon/jwt-auth ^0.5.12 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.12].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.12 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Any Error message?

Comment: I get :C:\xampp\my_xamp\htdocs\shops\laravel55>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package tymon/jwt-auth could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

Comment: Having the same problem as the OP with PHP 7.3.1 and Laravel 5.8.26.

Answer (score 15):

This command worked for me in Laravel 8 to Laravel 9.11:

```
composer require -w tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs
```

**composer.json**

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.11",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a (temporary) solution.
To get Laravel 5.8 compatibility, perform:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth ^1.0.0-rc.4.1
```

See discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1764).

Comment: And by the way, was able to use build in Laravel Bcryt cipher then ... straight from the shelf ... and I suppose Bcryt is the top in market at the moment ... :)

Comment: Not so temporary)

Answer (score 2):

use "--ignore-platform-reqs"

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 1):

> To install this package you will need:
>
> ```
> Laravel 4 or 5 (see compatibility table)
> PHP 5.4 +
> ```
>
> Install via composer - edit your composer.json to require the package.
>
> ```
> "require": {
>     "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*" 
> }
> ```
>
> Then run `composer update` in your terminal to pull it in.

The installation is there https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation
There is nothing said about `dev-master`, try with `0.5.*`

Comment: I am using "php": ">=7.0.0",( FYI: laravel 5.5.13 and composer 1.5.2), Does it still aply to php  7... ?

Comment: Yes, there you go

Comment: yes, what Thielicious? what must I do ? because I have php 7 . Must I downgrade to php 5.6 maybe? is that what You say ?

Comment: @Neo Sono  Excuse me? I am not the one who made this API. If it says `5.4 +` there is no need to downgrade so follow the installation because according to your compatibility this should actually work. Go to the repository under Issues, I see there are people having diverse problems

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/2083)

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may get a 0.5 version by a simple : `composer require tymon/jwt-auth`

To specify from 0.5, you may use `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:^0.5`

Comment: No luck : I get : 
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                       
  Could not find package tymon/jwt-auth at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability when I : composer require tymon/jwt-auth and when I specify I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have  "minimum-stability" in your composer.json?

Comment: Actually I am unable to recreate your issue with any setting of stability.

Comment: No I do not have minimum-stability. ..what/wher do you suggest I add ?

Comment: What could be making you to be unable to recreate my issue ?

Comment: Your entire composer.json. You should also include clearly the error you see in the original question text.

Answer (score 0):

To install the tymon/jwt-auth package in PHP laravel, one should follow the following steps:

Composer.json require should be like this:

```
"require": {
       "php": ">=5.5.9",
       "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
       "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
   },
```

Then in config/app.php put the following in the providers array:

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class
```

Then in the aliases array in the config/app.php add the following

```
'JWTAuth'   => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTFactory::class
```

Then type the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Note: Various tutorial will suggest you the following php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuthProviders\JWTAuthServiceProvider" but befor that try the above command ie without --provider and it will work

Then type:

```
php artisan jwt:generate
```

After this step you can verify the generated key in app/config/jwt.php as mentioned below:

```
'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've moved on with Java Spring MVC 4/5 AND HIBERNATE... AND ITS LOT OF FUN THERE... WELL GOOD BYE TO PHP. ..

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8:

```sh
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:^1.0.2
```

Answer (score -1):

```bash
npm install --save jwt-simple
```

Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How could the given command install a PHP package?

Answer (score -2):

according to my idea better use below command.

**composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs**

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Isn't this the same command that has been part of at least three other answers on this site? Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you share some new insights

Comment: don't copy existing answer